# Mongodb returns no result on any match query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data is like

```
myData[
    {
       id : 1,
       name : "a1",
       order : {
         id : 1,
         name : "o1",
         status : "2"
       }
    },
    {
       id : 2,
       name : "a2",
       order : {
         id : 1,
         name : "o1",
         status : "2"
       }
    },
    {
       id : 3,
       name : "a1",
       order : {
         id : 1,
         name : "o2",
         status : "3"
       }
    }
    ]
```

when I tried to query :

```
db.myData.find({
   "order" : {
      id : 1
   }
})
```

Same as

```
db.myData.find({ "order.id" :  1})
```

I expect 3 results but it returns nothing and when I tried to

```
db.myData.find({
   "order" : {
         id : 1,
         name : "o2",
         status : "3"
   }
})
```

it returns a result. Where is the problem?

Comment: is that all three documents are sub-documents?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing something wrong.

Definitely the `db.myData.find({ "order" : { id : 1 } })` should return nothing, because it looks for a specific subdocument `{id : 1}`.

On the other hand the second query should work correctly: `db.myData.find({ "order.id" : 1})` and especially if `db.myData.find({ "order" : { id : 1, name : "o2", status : "3" } })` gives you something.

Comment: Yes first one is exact match query but second one should correct. Third one for show mongodb online :D

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mydata.find({"order.id" : 1})
```

This query should work fine. It looks like you are somewhere overriding default `_id` field behaviour of your document.

Comment: I renamed fields before write here. I have _id field also

Comment: Can you please paste result here when you run `db.mydata.findOne()`?